# Wait for response in the main Java class after calling the instance and fuction in other Java class in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, multithreading, callback

Due to the delay in api call and response the data is not getting in time and I'm using delay to get reponse. If there the reponse is delayed more than my timer limit I get null error. Is there any better way to achieve this?

Here is my code in UrlCalls.java

```
public void getProfile()
{
    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(con);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    progressDialog.show();
    AuthTokenGenerator authtoken = new AuthTokenGenerator(con);
    Authenticator profilerequest = new Authenticator(Request.Method.POST, UrlBag.PROFILE, authtoken.getToken(data),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject profileresponse) {
                    response = String.valueOf(profileresponse);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(con,"Couldn't connect to server right now.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
    {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("customer_id", data.GetData(SharedDataHandler.CUSTOMER_ID));
            return params;
        }

    };

    int socketTimeout = 1000;//30 seconds - change to what you want
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    profilerequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(con);
    requestQueue.add(profilerequest);
}
```

And I'm calling this in my main thread.

```
final UrlCalls callProfile=new UrlCalls(this,data);
    callProfile.getProfile();
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                jObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(callProfile.getResponse()));
                if (!jObject.equals(""))
                {
                    JSONObject customer = jObject.getJSONObject("customer");
                    customername.setText(customer.getString("customer_name"));
                    data.SaveData(SharedDataHandler.FULL_NAME, customer.getString("customer_name"));
                    customeremail.setText(customer.getString("email"));
                    data.SaveData(SharedDataHandler.EMAIL, customer.getString("email"));
                    customerphone.setText(customer.getString("mobile"));
                    data.SaveData(SharedDataHandler.MOBILE, customer.getString("mobile"));
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Server Request time out.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            catch(JSONException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error occurred while processing the data.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Couldn't connect to server right now.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: similar questions are asked [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027222/asynctask-method-causing-problems-in-my-logic) and [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44025965/java-android-asynchttpclient-convert-byteresponsebody-to-inputstream) ... please learn how to work with async methods  obviously you should, AGAIN, move code to the callback (onResponse)

Comment: update your UI in on response method